# Using squid to anonymize HTTP traffic

Tags: proxy, http, squid

I'm trying to set up a SQUID server on Ubuntu to anonymize all HTTP traffic.

The goal is to hide the source IP make all the requests appear to be generated from the SQUID porxy.

I tried with the deafult configuartion but is not working as expected. How should I edit the squid.conf file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'not working as expected'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your problem is with the X-Forwarded-For: header that Squid inserts in the outgoing request. To remove it, use forwarded_for directive as described here:

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/

Comment: +1 that is definitely the case.