# How does a proxy server work for anonymous browsing?

Tags: linux, networking, security, proxy, internet

I have seen that at many places like colleges and schools block sites like Facebook, Myspace.

In some cases people are able to use a proxy sites and proxy softwares(ultrasurf,gpass etc.) to bypass the filter and access the blocked content.

Yesterday I have tried ultrasurf to get an understanding of how a proxy works. With the proxy configured I checked my IP using website www.whatismyip.com and I find that it is showing a different IP address from what I see when no proxy is configured.  It is showing my location as if I was in Canada, but I am from India.

So I have the following questions:

1. How do proxies work?
2. How does ultrasurf or any other proxy software is able to do this?
3. How can I setup my own proxy (it is only for learning purpose)?
4. Can I use Squid for this purpose?

If you know of any good tutorials, electronic boos, or references please suggest them.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. How do proxies work?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

> 2. How does ultrasurf or any other proxy software is able to do this?

Their servers are located in different countries and your traffic goes through them.

> 3. How can I setup my own proxy (it is only for learning purpose)?

In Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid

In Windows: http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/InstallingAndConfiguringSquidNTProxy

> 4. Can I use Squid for this purpose?

Yes

Comment: It is only as anonymous as the folks running the service are willing to protect the connection information/logging...

Comment: I have installed squid successfully but for anonymous browsing using it i still can't access banned sites.i have read http://serverfault.com/questions/70448/using-squid-to-anonymize-http-traffic but still i am not getting it.So please explain it a little more

Comment: Installing a local proxy does not "circumvent" any existing web browsing restrictions if the proxy is still going though the same controlled connection/path and your system is going through the proxy now. Where is your proxy located in relation to the infrastructure that is controlling/limiting access to certain sites and which port is it operating on?

Answer (score 0):

Squid is a bit of a workhorse for personal use. Something like https://www.banu.com/tinyproxy should be easier. Even http://www.torproject.org/